# Publishing frequency in rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
In rosjava tutorial I have seen that it uses Thread.sleep(1000) in the publisher to publish the data with 1Hz frequency...Is there any function (like in roscpp ros::Rate loop_rate(1) etc)...???
Thanks and regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33677/publishing-frequency-in-rosjava/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not yet. Feel free to file a feature request if you'd like to be notified when that is available: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1